# Is it possible to convert a .drmz file to .pdf knowing the password?

Tags: pdf, passwords, drm

I have n `.drmz` files which I display with Javelin PDF Reader.
Obviously to read the content I need a password, which I have, the same for each file.

Is it possible to convert them to `.pdf`, so I can transfer them to mobile and/or view them without having to open Javelin3 and enter the password each time?
Or is this `.drmz` format made on purpose to avoid converting (and distributing) `.pdf`  files even having the password?

- n stands for number of files

Answer (score 1):

`.drmz` is a PDF file, where DRM protection is added by Drumlin Security's Publisher. It's a proprietary encryption format. You need Drumlin Publisher to remove the encryption.